# Select with 2 count on 3 tables laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have 3 tables (establishment, staff, resident) and I want to get the name of the Establishment and the number of resident and staff for each Establishment in one query. But I don't know if it's possible.

I tried this :

```
DB::table('etablissements')
  ->select(array('etablissements.nom',
    DB::raw('COUNT(residents.id) as nbResidents'),
    DB::raw('COUNT(personnels.id) as nbPersonnels')))
  ->join('residents','etablissements.id','=','residents.etablissement_id')
  ->join('personnels','etablissements.id','=','personnels.etablissement_id')
  ->groupBy('etablissements.nom')->get();
```

But the results are not good. Can you help me?

I want an array with all the names of establishments and for each establishment the number of staff and residents who are attached to it.

Here you can see what I get but the numbers are wrong: https://puu.sh/tL6Jg/7d830067e1.png

There is no  establishments with the same name, and the result are the same with the id. I get the same result with the query in SQL, I'm not sure i'm doing it the right way. https://puu.sh/tMMFI/49bd788501.png 
If I take the first establishment I shoul have 28 residents and 36 staff members.

**Solution :**
I've forgot to put DISTINCT after each COUNT.

Comment: Please be specific, what result exactly do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: Did you try to write a SQL query directly into your database to match the results?

Comment: You may have establishments with the same name. Try grouping by establishment ID.

Comment: There is no  establishments with the same name, and the result are the same with the id. I get the same result with the query in SQL, I'm not sure i'm doing it the right way. https://puu.sh/tMMFI/49bd788501.png